# using django ajax uploader in view and template

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, upload

I have been trying to get `django ajax uploader` to work in my `django application`.I must be brain dead :( because I couldn't get it to work-which was supposedly an easy thing ,according to many users of the code.

I have installed the [django ajax uploader](https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader)  and added it to the installed apps.I decided not to use `STATIC_URL`s and instead put the `css and js` files into `MEDIA_ROOT` and used `MEDIA_URL` to serve them.

I have also included the [anonymous function](http://pastebin.com/Yx2JpgjD) inside `<script>` tags in `start.html` as mentioned in [step4 of the doc](https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader#step-4-set-up-your-template)- changing the action to `{% url ajax_upload %}`

In my `start.html` page,I need a file input element such that ,when it select a file,uploads the file to a location on the server.

so I created the html like this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{% url upload_without_ajax %}"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="fselect" id="file-uploader"> </input>
</form>
```

the start.html is rendered by `views.start` method

views.py -

```
def start(request, template_name):
    csrf_token = get_token(request)
    reqctx = RequestContext(request,{'csrf_token': csrf_token })
    return render_to_response(template_name,reqctx)

import_uploader = AjaxFileUploader()
```

Here is my question.

1.Is giving `id=file-uploader` to the input element enough to cause the file upload?Or do I have to call an `$('#file-uploader').change(` in my javascript?

2.I only need to get the selected file to be written to the `MEDIA_ROOT/uploads` folder ,which is what I think the default `LocalUploadBackend` does. In the urls.py I mapped the `views.import_uploader` to the url ajax_upload

```
url(r'^ajax_upload$', 'views.import_uploader',name='ajax_upload'),
```

Still, no file upload occurs..

I couldn't make out much from the given code in the github site.If somebody can help me with this,it will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Everything except html seems fine. However, you should check if you have python 2.7, since 2.6+ is not compatible with django-ajax-uploader. (or vice versa!)

If you proceed with python 2.7, you should clone https://github.com/lazerscience/django-ajax-uploader

```
git clone https://github.com/lazerscience/django-ajax-uploader
cd django-ajax-uploader
python setup.py install
```

This should suffice. (Do not forget to change html like the example in the repo, yes #file-upload works by itself with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working to my django-ajax file upload also at the moment. But my template part is working fine by placing the default.

Where file-uploader is an id for div not the actual input file type. From what I read in fileuploader.js, this script will create the file upload element for you though with a standard style. I'm not a js guru but I believe you can customize that within the fileuploader.js??

In my js function below I'm trying to pass the pk of my instance as a parameter for the ajax by trying to add new item that is name and value within `params: {..}` and `action: "{% url ajax_upload %}",` is pointig to this `url(r'^ajax-upload$', 'yourapp.views.import_uploader', name="ajax_upload"),`

I hope this help or not..give me vote down :[

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>-->
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}ajaxuploader/js/fileuploader.js" ></script>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}ajaxuploader/css/fileuploader.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>

        function createUploader(pk){            
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
                action: "{% url ajax_upload %}",
                debug: true,
                multiple: false,                    
                onComplete : function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                if(responseJSON.success) {
                    alert("success!");
                } else {
                    alert("upload failed!");
                }                    
                },                    
                params: {
                'csrf_token': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                'csrf_name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
                'csrf_xname': 'X-CSRFToken',
                'pk': pk,
                },           
            });
        };

        $(document).ready(function(){
            createUploader({{instance.id}});
        });          
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="file-uploader">        
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```